# Regular expression to search text "From TableName" using VisualStudio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am using the below regular expression to search sql script file from VisualStudio find text in files dialogbox:

```
from\s+(Table123|\[Table123\])\s*
```

Output:

```
FROM [Table123] [i]

FROM Table123 I

FROM Table123Extended t1

FROM Table123";

How can I modify my regular expression to eliminate third result 

1. FROM [Table123] [i]         (correct)

2. FROM Table123 I             (correct) 

3. FROM Table123Extended t1    (incorrect)

4. FROM Table123";             (correct)
```

Comment: If you change the regex to `from\s+(Table123|\[Table123\])\s` it will look for a space at the end of those 2 table names hence excluding the 3rd one but there are many other ways to achieve this. It depends on other constraints you may have.

Comment: Thanks @Neal for providing the clue, I edited my question and also posted the working solution.

Comment: Replace `\s*` with `[\s"]`

Answer (score 1):

from\s+(Table123|[Table123])(\s+|")

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure thematch ends with a double quote or a whitespace, thus, you should replace `\s*` with `[\s"]` and use

```
from\s+(Table123|\[Table123\])[\s"]
```

The `[\s"]` is a * character class* that matches any single char that is defined in the class, hete, a whitespace or a double quote.